# how to set the vertical scroll bar in firefox to be in the left side?

Tags: html, firefox, textarea, scrollbar

i want that the vertical  scroll bar that show in textarea in fire fox will show in the left side,
i have site with 'rtl' direction, 
and in IE its o.k , in the left side - (oposide the text).

Comment: I would personally hate a website that does this  :)

That said, I don't know how to do this.. hehe.

Comment: seriously question the value of changing a behaviour like this. That doesn't mean you can't, but I don't see this being of any value other than "hey, neat! i didn't know you could do that"

Comment: I can imagine people who write from right to left this being more "natural"?

Comment: I wonder why people like to discuss whether something is useful or good or whatever instead of giving a helpful answer...

Comment: Interesting point okoman. Is advising against a request a good answer or not?

Comment: You mean on specific site or change the browser UI itself?

Comment: English speaking people think that browsers are made only for them. That said, all the answers which oppose the change are rubbish. Before opposing my comment, go and have a look at the Windows for Arabic or Hebrew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox considers it a usability feature that a scrollbar appears on the same side all the time for a given user no matter what direction the text in the page uses.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=330863

So if your browser is using some RTL language such as Hebrew, then the scrollbars are always on the left, and if your browser is using English then it's always on the right.  There is a preference you can set in about:config (layout.scrollbar.side) that overrides this but a web author has no control over it.

Answer (score 3):

You could always do this with a custom scrollbar which is set to look like the standard one. But as others have said I wouldn't recommend. Changing the UI is this way is on the whole a bad idea.

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it, because it breaks what users expect, but here you go:

1. Enter about:config in the Location bar
2. Type layout.scrollbar.side in the "Filter"
3. Double-click the
   layout.scrollbar.side preference and
   change it to 3

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with the other answers here, I would seriously consider if you'd want to do this (from a ease-of-use standpoint).

That said, even though you got it working in IE, I don't think your use of the RTL setting is correct. I'm not sure the effects it has but I think it's more for allowing users to write in a language that reads/writes right-to-left.